# How do I automount a unionfs-fuse filesystem?

Tags: fuse, autofs, unionfs

I can run the shell command:

```
unionfs-fuse /changedata=RW:/immutedata=RO -o cow /data
```

This mounts the filesystem exactly how I want to.  Now I need to incorporate it into the automounter so that it's remounted upon demand.

What I tried in /etc/auto.misc:

```
/data -fstype=fuse,cow /changedata=RW:/immutedata=RO
```

What automount --debug -f /etc/auto.master says when I do ls /data:

```
handle_packet: type = 5
handle_packet_missing_direct: token 19, name /data, request pid 6063
attempting to mount entry /data
lookup_mount: lookup(file): looking up /data
lookup_mount: lookup(file): /data -> -fstype=fuse,cow /changedata=RW:/immutedata=RO
parse_mount: parse(sun): expanded entry: -fstype=fuse,cow /changedata=RW:/immutedata=RO
parse_mount: parse(sun): gathered options: fstype=fuse,cow
parse_mount: parse(sun): dequote("/changedata=RW:/immutedata=RO") -> /changedata=RW:/immutedata=RO
parse_mapent: parse(sun): gathered options: fstype=fuse,cow
parse(sun): invalid location 
dev_ioctl_send_fail: token = 19
failed to mount /data
```

Google reveals little.  Man pages are rather empty on the incorporation of this filesystem.

Maybe I should just put it in /etc/fstab and ask users to remount?

Comment: 4 years on and I can't find an example on the web.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat I have provided an answer that works :)

Answer (score 3):

I know it is too late to answer but adding the following to /etc/fstab in Ubuntu works,

```
/dir/A=RW:/dir/B=RO /dir/my-union fuse.unionfs-fuse allow_other,cow,use_ino  0   0
```

Comment: Where should that line be written to? [edit] your answer to amend it!

Comment: I specifically am trying automount since some of this stuff is remote the mount can go stale and/or missing for a variety of reasons

Answer (score 2):

### automounting unionfs with autofs

**TLDR**: create the following entry in `/etc/auto.misc` and include it in your `etc/auto.master` (as outlined below).

```
data    -fstype=fuse,cow,allow_other :unionfs\#/changedata=RW\:/immutedata=RO
```

---

**Bonus**: Creating a unionfs automount on top of nfs automounts (to illustrate how to properly configure autofs)

When using NFSv4, enable IMAPD in `/etc/default/nfs-common`

```
NEED_IDMAPD=yes
```

If you want autofs to always create directories for your mounts, enable browse_mode in `/etc/autofs.conf`

```
browse_mode = yes
```

Now to the core part: in your `/etc/auto.master` add the following lines

```
# automount all nfs volumes under /nfs and misc filesystems under /mnt
/nfs   /etc/auto.nfs
/mnt   /etc/auto.misc
```

autofs will mount all filesystems specified in `/etc/auto.nfs` under `/nfs/<mount>` and all filesystems specified in `/etc/auto.misc` under `/mnt/<mount>`.

In my `/etc/auto.nfs` I have the following (example) entries:

```
# FileServer: nfs data configuration
data01 -fstype=nfs4,ro,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,nosuid,tcp,allow_other 192.168.3.100:/mnt/data01
data02 -fstype=nfs4,ro,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,nosuid,tcp,allow_other 192.168.3.100:/mnt/data02
data03 -fstype=nfs4,ro,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,nosuid,tcp,allow_other 192.168.3.100:/mnt/data03
data04 -fstype=nfs4,ro,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,nosuid,tcp,allow_other 192.168.3.100:/mnt/data04
data05 -fstype=nfs4,ro,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,nosuid,tcp,allow_other 192.168.3.100:/mnt/data05
```

And in my `/etc/auto.misc` I added the following entry for unionfs

```
# unionfs mount of all /nfs/data* mounts into /mnt/data
data    -fstype=fuse,allow_other,use_ino,ro,noatime :unionfs\#/nfs/data01=RO\:/nfs/data02=RO\:/nfs/data03=RO\:/nfs/data04=RO\:/nfs/data05=RO
```

Make sure all files have a permission of `644` ( adjust with `chown 644 /etc/auto.{nfs,misc}` if necessary)

Then you can enable autofs and restart the service.

```
# reload autofs to enable all shares
systemctl enable autofs
systemctl restart autofs
```

You should now be able to do a `ls /mnt/data`